# Get rid of CAPTCHA in Facebook

Tags: facebook, facebook-messenger, captcha

I have a Facebook account for two days only.

How long will it take Facebook to believe I'm *not* a spammer (or my account to grow *mature* enough) so I don't have to write irritating CAPTCHA each time I want to paste a link into chat?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe and haven't found this (length of time till maturity) listed. It's most likely intentionally ambiguous to keep those that are suspicious guessing. Things you can try

- Verifying your account by cell number
- Interacting with Facebook profiles (friends)
- Avoiding proxies (sacrifice of privacy but some proxies allow many spammers to be welcomed)

Comment: Thank you! I "pass" all your points (have verified account with cell phone, have 33 friends and not using proxy). And I still see CAPTCHA (only in chat, not when putting URL as a part of comment, strange?). It seems, that this is something odd and unusual. Seems, that I just have to learn to live with this. Pity...